# Запятая после прямой речи перед указательным местоимением

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

> Не удивляйтесь, если зазывалы кричат вам: «НОУ МИКРОВЭЙВ!»,  – так они
>   рекламируют вам своё заведение.

Запятая ведь закрывает придаточное, нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Не удивляйтесь, если зазывалы кричат вам: «НОУ МИКРОВЭЙВ!» - так они рекламируют вам своё заведение.**

***Запятая не нужна, так как прямая речь заканчивается восклицательным знаком. Ставим тире.***

Подробнее здесь: [Знаки препинания при прямой речи](http://lingvotech.com/znaki_prepinaniya_pri_pryamoy_rechi)

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас я увидела, что придаточное вовсе не закрывается после прямой речи, а длится до конца предложения.

Comment: А если бы было: "Не удивляйтесь, если зазывалы кричат вам: «НОУ МИКРОВЭЙВ!», - это реклама"? То есть я попробовала почётче обозначить придаточное; как тогда? Главное: не удивляйтесь - это реклама.

Comment: А мне кажется, что закрывается.Пройдите, пожалуйста, по ссылке. Там есть похожие примеры.